# Lighttpd configuration multiple subdomains

Tags: domain-server, lighttpd

I have a Lighttpd server as a front end for Ruby on rails.

Some subdomains (`server1.domain.com`, `server2.domain.com`) are configured with proxy.

But also have a standard static web server at `www.domain.com`.

It works, but the call without subdomain (`domain.com`) does not work.

How could I configure Lighttpd for it?

Configuration for proxy:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "www.domain." {
    alias.url = ( "/system/" => "/var/www/system/" )
        proxy.balance = "fair"
        proxy.server  = ( "" => (
            ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 5750)
             )
        )
}
```

Configuration for server1 and server2:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "server1.domain." {
    alias.url = ( "/system/" => "/var/www/system/" )
        proxy.balance = "fair"
        proxy.server  = ( "" => (
        ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 7757 ) ,
                ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 5222),
                ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 5223)
                )
    )
}

$HTTP["host"] =~ "server2.domain." {
    alias.url = ( "/system/" => "/var/www/system/" )
        proxy.balance = "fair"
        proxy.server  = ( "" => (
        ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 7787 ) ,
                ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 5282),
                ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 5283)
                )
    )
}
```

Comment: Could you post all configuration related to server1, server2 ?

Comment: I've added the configuration to the main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two solutions.

**First one**

Redirect traffic to the `www` if the domain is `domain.com`:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^domain\.com" {
        url.redirect = (
                "^/(.*)" => "http://www.domain.com/$1",
                ""       => "http://www.domain.com/"
        )
}
```

**Second one**

Handle traffic for both `www.domain.` and `domain.` (be careful about the duplicate content then). Replace the old rule for `www.domain.` by:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(^domain.)|(^www.domain.)" {
    alias.url = ( "/system/" => "/var/www/system/" )
        proxy.balance = "fair"
        proxy.server  = ( "" => (
            ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 5750)
             )
        )
}
```

Comment: I tried the First one solution and it worked fine. Thanks a lot.